# read file and copy modified data to other file

Tags: c#

I have some numbers under each oterh, like this:

```
71004
71006
71008
71026
71028
```

They are standing in a text file. And I want to read the textfile and then modify the textfile, so it becomes:

71004|71006|71008|71026|71028|

I try it like this:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file1 = @"D:\Docs\ImportDataInNAV\ImportVendorNumbers.txt";
            using (StreamReader stream = File.OpenText(file1))
            {
                string s = String.Empty;
                while ((s = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    foreach (var line in s)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Thank you

I try it like this:

```
  using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\\Docs\\ImportDataInNAV\\ImportVendorNumbers.txt"))

            using (FileStream writeStream = File.OpenWrite("D:\\file2.txt"))
            {
                var output = string.Join("|", File.ReadLines(writeStream));
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(writeStream);

                // create a buffer to hold the bytes 
                byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;

                // while the read method returns bytes
                // keep writing them to the output stream
                while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                {
                    //writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead) ;
                    File.WriteAllText(filepath, output);
                }



            }
```

Comment: How you know it's modified?

Comment: You know, at the moment you're just printing those numbers to the console?

Comment: So you just want to join all the lines together with a "|" in between the vaules? Heard of String.Join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to read the textfile and then modify the textfile, so it
>   becomes:
>
> 71004|71006|71008|71026|71028|

Use `string.Join` to form `|` delimited string.

```
var output -string.Join("|",File.ReadLines(filepath));

File.WriteAllText(filepath, output);
```

Not sure `|` at the end is intentional, if it is desired output concat `|` at the end to output before writing.

Comment: You don't really need all the code you posted, you just need two lines in my answer. Did you try this?

Comment: Thank you!! That did the job

Answer (score 0):

how about Run your code like
yourprograme.exe > outputfile.txt